# Altering SQL Stored procedure to have max result be 100

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am attempting to manipulate the results of a stored procedure to not expel a result greater than 100.

Essentially if the result is >=100 I want my result to be 100.

Here is what I currently have

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_5_ServiceLevel]
    @Wallboard int 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    
    --select a.ServiceName, a.ServiceRow, a.ServicePercentage, isnull(round((sum(b.SLAMet+0.0)/sum(b.AnsweredCalls+0.0))*100.,0),0) SLPercentage,
    select a.ServiceName, a.ServiceRow, a.ServicePercentage, isnull(round(sum(isNull(b.SLAMet+0.0,0.0))/sum(isNull(b.AnsweredCalls+0.0,0.0))*100.,0),0) SLPercentage,
    isNull(max(b.DateTimeStamp),' ') DateTimeStamp
    from CS5_QueueGroups2 A
    left outer join CS750_1 b on a.QueueName = b.QueueName
    where a.ServiceMonitor = @Wallboard
    group by a.ServiceName, a.ServiceRow, a.ServicePercentage
    order by a.ServiceRow
    
END
```

if a result is greater than 100, I want it to not surpass that 100 mark.

anything >=100 must be = 100

Comment: select top 100 a.ServiceName ...

Comment: That would get my the top 100 results correct? 

What I receive with my current USP is this = 


ServiceName ServiceRow ServicePercentage SLPercentage DateTimeStamp
C CS        1 85 172.000000 2022-11-09 15:37:01.000




what I want is this 

ServiceName ServiceRow ServicePercentage SLPercentage DateTimeStamp
C CS        1 85 ******100.000000******** 2022-11-09 15:37:01.000

Comment: *expel a result greater than 100.* What does this mean? Are you after at most 100 rows or something else? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Sorry, its my first question I've asked on here. 

So I want to limit my result to be (100)

Currently running my USP as is, it gives me a result of 172, but I want my end result to be 100.

Comment: If your calculations yield values over 100%, are you totally sure the maths is correct? I recommend adding example data to your question, showing how your current query can get 170%. Replacing values that exceed 100% seems to be very suspicious to me, and if I saw it in code I'd want a HUGE comment block explaining why. (For example, my gut feel is that SLAMet might be recorded at the end of a call and Answered is recorded at the start of a call, or something similar. But to get a correct % you need to allocate SLAMet to when the call was answered.)

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_5_ServiceLevel]
  @Wallboard int 
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON; 


select a.ServiceName,
   a.ServiceRow, 
   iif(ServicePercentage >= 100, 100, [ServicePercentage]) as [ServicePercentage],
   isnull(round(sum(isNull(b.SLAMet+0.0,0.0))/sum(isNull(b.AnsweredCalls+0.0,0.0))*100.,0),0) as SLPercentage,
   isNull(max(b.DateTimeStamp),' ') as DateTimeStamp
from CS5_QueueGroups2 A
left outer join CS750_1 b on a.QueueName = b.QueueName
where a.ServiceMonitor = @Wallboard
group by a.ServiceName, a.ServiceRow, a.ServicePercentage
order by a.ServiceRow

END
```

If it's the SLPercentage field you're looking to display conditionally I would wrap the whole statement in virtual table like this. Otherwise you will have to express the SLPrecentage formula twice in the conditional statement. Makes things hard to follow, IMO.

```
select ServiceName, ServiceRow, ServicePercentage, iif(SLPercentage >= 100, 100, SLPercentage) as SLPercentage, SLPercentage, DateTimeStamp from (
   select a.ServiceName,
          a.ServiceRow, 
          ServicePercentage,
          isnull(round(sum(isNull(b.SLAMet+0.0,0.0))/sum(isNull(b.AnsweredCalls+0.0,0.0))*100.,0),0) as SLPercentage,
          isNull(max(b.DateTimeStamp),' ') as DateTimeStamp
   from CS5_QueueGroups2 A
   left outer join CS750_1 b on a.QueueName = b.QueueName
   where a.ServiceMonitor = @Wallboard
   group by a.ServiceName, a.ServiceRow, a.ServicePercentage
   order by a.ServiceRow) 
as t1
```

Comment: That would get my the top 100 results correct? What I receive with my current USP is this = ServiceName ServiceRow ServicePercentage SLPercentage DateTimeStamp C CS 1 85 172.000000 2022-11-09 15:37:01.000 what I want is this ServiceName ServiceRow ServicePercentage SLPercentage DateTimeStamp C CS 1 85 ******100.000000******** 2022-11-09 15:37:01.000

Comment: If it's over 100 just display it as 100?

Comment: correct if its over 100 just display is as 100

Comment: Check the edit in my answer. I'm assuming MS-SQL here.

`iif`  is what you need.